# i input a value to make looping work exact times, but it does not work

Tags: c

For example, as the following code, i want to work this loop 5 times, so i input 5 in b,and the results show it only worked once. please help me thanks

```
while(scanf("%s",&a)!=EOF){
    scanf("%d",&b);
    for(c=1;c<=b;c++){
        char d[4];
        scanf("%s",&d);
        printf("%s\n",d);  }}
```

Comment: You should read the documentation for `scanf`.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&d);` --> `scanf("%3s",d);`

Comment: @Broman Can you please elaborate a little?

Comment: @SouravGhosh You're right. I was unclear. What I meant was that you should always check the return value from scanf to see if the assignment was successful.

Comment: And also that you should check what value you actually assigned when you are debugging.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add information what input you enter, what output you get and what you want to get. Add a main function with all necessary variable declarations to your code to allow us to compile and test your code.

Comment: i printf b and it's 5, but loop just can't work 5 times, dont know why(and without while loop for scanf char a, it works fine , dont know why too...)

Comment: sorry, im new in this forum, i learned programing a week, i use codeblocks and i dont know why i cant use "watch tool", it shows nothing.  i tried to post whole code on questions but forum did not allow me to do that...

Comment: Also what's that with your username :F

Comment: Please fix a [mcve]

Comment: sorry, if my name offend you... just want to be more funny...

Comment: Also study [ask]

Comment: No problem. Learning how to ask on forums is not trivial.

Comment: `while(scanf("%s",&a)!=EOF)` isn't code that I would write, instead `while(scanf("%s", a) == 1)`. Firstly `a` decays to the required pointer, secondly the return value of `1` is the only successful outcome. Your version would accept the return value of `0` which is a mistake.

Comment: thank you, i was trying to give char d more space, and it finally works... the whole problem is that i have to input char a[], and input b for how many to test, and d[] is the value i want to compare with a[], and output the compare result

Comment: i think the whole trouble is abt how to use a string correctly, but based on my current knowledge, it still too difficult for me

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
char a[4];
while(scanf("%s",&a)!=EOF){
    int b,c;
    scanf("%d",&b);
    for(c=1;c<=b;c++){
        char d[100];
        int e,f=0,g=0;

        scanf("%s",&d);
        for(e=0;e<=3;e++)
            if(a[e]==d[e])
                f++;
        for(e=0;e<=3;e++)
            if(a[e]!=d[e]&&a[e]==d[(e+1)%4]||a[e]==d[(e+2)%4]||a[e]==d[(e+3)%4])
                g++;
        printf("%dA%dB\n",f,g);
    }
}
    return 0;}
```

I change the size of "d" to 100, and it finally works, the first for loop can run five times as I input 5 as "b", but still don't know why it could not work when I only give "d" size of 4...